# Converting a file <class 'bytes'> into a directory location as string

Tags: python-3.x, video-processing

I am having trouble with a program I wrote that reads in video files and creates images from every frame. My code is as follows:

```
directory = os.fsencode(treated_directory_in_str)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
     print(type(file))
    # Incompatible types - file need to be directory location as str
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     filenoext = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
     if filename.endswith(".avi"):
       vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
       success, image = vidcap.read()
       count = 0
       success = True
       while success:
         cv2.imwrite("%sframe%d.jpg" % filenoext, count, image)  # save frame as JPEG file
         success, image = vidcap.read()
         print('Read a new frame: ', success)
         count += 1
         continue
     else:
         continue
```

And I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../file.py", line 19, in <module>
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
4.2.0
<class 'bytes'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!